# Powershell domain join directly to specified OU not working

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to join a computer to a domain with a specified OU by using Powershell.

```
Add-Computer -domainname mydomain.net -OUPath "OU=W2k8 R2 Servers,OU=Servers,DC=mydomain,DC=net" -cred alloweduser@mydomain.net -passthru –verbose
```

I get the Error:

```
This command cannot be executed on target computer('ch88s170') due to following error: Access is denied.
```

When I use this command and do not specify a OU then it works!?

```
Add-Computer -domainname mydomain.net -cred alloweduser@mydomain.net -passthru –verbose
```

Could it be caused because of a Active Directory Policy restriction? Which one? What should i try next to find a solution?

P.S. Firewall is disabled, Powershell runing as Administrator without UAC, OS: Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: Can you manually move that computer account to the W2k8 OU?

Comment: Sounds like the account (alloweduser@mydomain.net) doesn't have permissions to create new objects in that OU. To check the permissions on the OU, open Active Directory Users and Computers, select View->Advanced Features, open the Properties of the OU, and switch to the Security tab. Make sure that the account (or, preferably, a group that contains the account), has the "Create all child objects" permission.

Comment: Both of you were right! It was a problem with the Permission. I though when a user can join to a domain the user have also the permisson to join directly to a OU, so i didn't check the permissions. After I added the "Create all child objects" the problem was solved! Thx a lot! P.S. How can I mark the question as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Adi Inbar has told me:

The account (alloweduser@mydomain.net) didn't have had permissions to create new objects in that OU.
I though when a user can join to a domain the user have also the permisson to join directly to a OU, so i didn't check the permissions. After I added the "Create all child objects" the problem was solved!